# Running evaluation issue - Tensorflow object detection api (EfficentDet)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

Running the evaluation on the test data i get the following error:

```py
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

And this, which might be the problem?

```py
INFO:tensorflow:A replica probably exhausted all examples. 
Skipping pending examples on other replicas.
```

This is the code for the evaluation on the test data

```py
!python workspace/model_main_tf2.py \
    --pipeline_config_path="/content/models/efficientdet_d4_coco17_tpu-32/pipeline.config" \
    --model_dir="/content/models/efficientdet_d4_coco17_tpu-32" \
    --checkpoint_dir="/content/models/efficientdet_d4_coco17_tpu-32" \
    --alsologtostderr
```

Here is the config file:

```py
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 14
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 512
        max_dimension: 1024
        pad_to_max_dimension: false
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_efficientnet-b4_bifpn_keras"
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 4e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.03
          }
        }
        activation: SWISH
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.99
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.001
        }
        force_use_bias: true
      }
      bifpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        num_iterations: 7
        num_filters: 224
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 1.0
        x_scale: 1.0
        height_scale: 1.0
        width_scale: 1.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 4e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.01
            }
          }
          activation: SWISH
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.99
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.001
          }
          force_use_bias: true
        }
        depth: 224
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        kernel_size: 3
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
        use_depthwise: true
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        scales_per_octave: 3
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-08
        iou_threshold: 0.5
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 1.5
          alpha: 0.25
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
    add_background_class: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 2
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_scale_crop_and_pad_to_square {
      output_size: 1024
      scale_min: 0.1
      scale_max: 2.0
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.008
          total_steps: 300000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.001
          warmup_steps: 2500
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/content/pretrained_models/efficientdet_d4_coco17_tpu-32/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 5000
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  use_bfloat16: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/content/LabelsMap.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00024-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00003-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00007-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00019-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00011-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00022-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00023-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00010-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00015-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00014-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00008-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00001-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00004-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00002-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00013-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00017-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00005-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00016-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00000-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00021-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00012-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00006-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00020-of-00025"
  }
}
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/content/LabelsMap.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00018-of-00025"
    input_path: "/content/annotations/annotations-00009-of-00025"
  }
}
```

Here is the complete output when i run the evaluation:

```py
2021-02-08 05:25:09.253366: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
WARNING:tensorflow:Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
W0208 05:25:12.065460 140012639324032 model_lib_v2.py:1034] Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting sample_1_of_n_eval_examples: None
I0208 05:25:12.065674 140012639324032 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting sample_1_of_n_eval_examples: None
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I0208 05:25:12.065757 140012639324032 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting eval_num_epochs: 1
I0208 05:25:12.065824 140012639324032 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting eval_num_epochs: 1
WARNING:tensorflow:Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0. Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.
W0208 05:25:12.065912 140012639324032 model_lib_v2.py:1049] Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0. Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.
2021-02-08 05:25:12.076229: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-08 05:25:12.078450: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-02-08 05:25:12.084383: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-02-08 05:25:12.085080: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-08 05:25:12.085116: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2021-02-08 05:25:12.087591: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-02-08 05:25:12.087657: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
2021-02-08 05:25:12.090212: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-02-08 05:25:12.091102: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-02-08 05:25:12.094218: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-02-08 05:25:12.095557: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2021-02-08 05:25:12.100331: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2021-02-08 05:25:12.100468: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-02-08 05:25:12.101137: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-02-08 05:25:12.101764: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-02-08 05:25:12.102128: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX512F
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-02-08 05:25:12.102431: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-08 05:25:12.102585: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-02-08 05:25:12.103196: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-08 05:25:12.103223: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2021-02-08 05:25:12.103261: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-02-08 05:25:12.103282: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
2021-02-08 05:25:12.103295: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-02-08 05:25:12.103313: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-02-08 05:25:12.103328: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-02-08 05:25:12.103342: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2021-02-08 05:25:12.103359: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2021-02-08 05:25:12.103415: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-02-08 05:25:12.104052: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-02-08 05:25:12.104613: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-02-08 05:25:12.104651: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2021-02-08 05:25:12.856387: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-08 05:25:12.856446: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-02-08 05:25:12.856460: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-02-08 05:25:12.856682: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-02-08 05:25:12.857384: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-02-08 05:25:12.858009: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-02-08 05:25:12.858573: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:39] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
2021-02-08 05:25:12.858621: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 14353 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 7.0)
I0208 05:25:12.870367 140012639324032 ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py:144] EfficientDet EfficientNet backbone version: efficientnet-b4
I0208 05:25:12.870554 140012639324032 ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py:145] EfficientDet BiFPN num filters: 224
I0208 05:25:12.870640 140012639324032 ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py:147] EfficientDet BiFPN num iterations: 7
I0208 05:25:12.880502 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=32 output=48
I0208 05:25:12.909189 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=32 output=48
I0208 05:25:12.909347 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=16 output=24
I0208 05:25:13.042321 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=16 output=24
I0208 05:25:13.042510 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=24 output=32
I0208 05:25:13.363938 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=24 output=32
I0208 05:25:13.364143 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=40 output=56
I0208 05:25:13.683968 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=40 output=56
I0208 05:25:13.684169 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=80 output=112
I0208 05:25:14.169368 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=80 output=112
I0208 05:25:14.169568 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=112 output=160
I0208 05:25:14.644392 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=112 output=160
I0208 05:25:14.644582 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=192 output=272
I0208 05:25:15.287888 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=192 output=272
I0208 05:25:15.288102 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=320 output=448
I0208 05:25:15.442380 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:147] round_filter input=1280 output=1792
I0208 05:25:15.474397 140012639324032 efficientnet_model.py:458] Building model efficientnet with params ModelConfig(width_coefficient=1.4, depth_coefficient=1.8, resolution=380, dropout_rate=0.4, blocks=(BlockConfig(input_filters=32, output_filters=16, kernel_size=3, num_repeat=1, expand_ratio=1, strides=(1, 1), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=16, output_filters=24, kernel_size=3, num_repeat=2, expand_ratio=6, strides=(2, 2), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=24, output_filters=40, kernel_size=5, num_repeat=2, expand_ratio=6, strides=(2, 2), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=40, output_filters=80, kernel_size=3, num_repeat=3, expand_ratio=6, strides=(2, 2), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=80, output_filters=112, kernel_size=5, num_repeat=3, expand_ratio=6, strides=(1, 1), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=112, output_filters=192, kernel_size=5, num_repeat=4, expand_ratio=6, strides=(2, 2), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=192, output_filters=320, kernel_size=3, num_repeat=1, expand_ratio=6, strides=(1, 1), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise')), stem_base_filters=32, top_base_filters=1280, activation='simple_swish', batch_norm='default', bn_momentum=0.99, bn_epsilon=0.001, weight_decay=5e-06, drop_connect_rate=0.2, depth_divisor=8, min_depth=None, use_se=True, input_channels=3, num_classes=1000, model_name='efficientnet', rescale_input=False, data_format='channels_last', dtype='float32')
INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted datasets: ['/content/annotations/annotations-00018-of-00025', '/content/annotations/annotations-00009-of-00025']
I0208 05:25:15.696288 140012639324032 dataset_builder.py:163] Reading unweighted datasets: ['/content/annotations/annotations-00018-of-00025', '/content/annotations/annotations-00009-of-00025']
INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file: ['/content/annotations/annotations-00018-of-00025', '/content/annotations/annotations-00009-of-00025']
I0208 05:25:15.696582 140012639324032 dataset_builder.py:80] Reading record datasets for input file: ['/content/annotations/annotations-00018-of-00025', '/content/annotations/annotations-00009-of-00025']
INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 2
I0208 05:25:15.696693 140012639324032 dataset_builder.py:81] Number of filenames to read: 2
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 2 to match input file shards.
W0208 05:25:15.696779 140012639324032 dataset_builder.py:88] num_readers has been reduced to 2 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:`shuffle` is false, but the input data stream is still slightly shuffled since `num_readers` > 1.
W0208 05:25:15.697415 140012639324032 dataset_builder.py:94] `shuffle` is false, but the input data stream is still slightly shuffled since `num_readers` > 1.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:105: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
W0208 05:25:15.697919 140012639324032 deprecation.py:339] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:105: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:237: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
W0208 05:25:15.718755 140012639324032 deprecation.py:339] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:237: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
W0208 05:25:19.670241 140012639324032 deprecation.py:339] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/inputs.py:282: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W0208 05:25:21.127015 140012639324032 deprecation.py:339] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/inputs.py:282: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
INFO:tensorflow:Waiting for new checkpoint at /content/models/efficientdet_d4_coco17_tpu-32
I0208 05:25:23.790350 140012639324032 checkpoint_utils.py:139] Waiting for new checkpoint at /content/models/efficientdet_d4_coco17_tpu-32
INFO:tensorflow:Found new checkpoint at /content/models/efficientdet_d4_coco17_tpu-32/ckpt-6
I0208 05:25:23.791489 140012639324032 checkpoint_utils.py:148] Found new checkpoint at /content/models/efficientdet_d4_coco17_tpu-32/ckpt-6
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:434: UserWarning: `tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase` is deprecated and will be removed after 2020-10-11. To update it, simply pass a True/False value to the `training` argument of the `__call__` method of your layer or model.
  warnings.warn('`tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase` is deprecated and '
2021-02-08 05:25:31.670912: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-02-08 05:25:31.671446: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 2000155000 Hz
INFO:tensorflow:A replica probably exhausted all examples. Skipping pending examples on other replicas.
I0208 05:25:36.730515 140012639324032 model_lib_v2.py:890] A replica probably exhausted all examples. Skipping pending examples on other replicas.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "workspace/model_main_tf2.py", line 113, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "workspace/model_main_tf2.py", line 88, in main
    wait_interval=300, timeout=FLAGS.eval_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 1087, in eval_continuously
    global_step=global_step)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 956, in eager_eval_loop
    for evaluator in evaluators:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Anyone know what is wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: hi. could you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the number of classes to the original one. I guess it is 90 for the COCO dataset. Or if it was a custom model make sure that number of classes matched to the one you trained your model with.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the error when writing in checkpoint ckpt-0.index  so I removed .index and keeping only ckpt-0 it worked for me  so I suggest verifying your checkpoint path and fine_tune path or maybe you have an error in your test record file
as a remark before launching the evaluation command you have to train the model first then the --checkpoint_dir attribute will have the path to the folder which has been trained and which contain all your checkpoints

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this, the problem for me was that I was running the training job in one terminal, then in another terminal I was running this model evaluation job (as the [instructions say clearly to do](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#evaluating-the-model-optional)). This opaque error message came about for me, because the evaluation job was also trying to grab and use the GPU. For me, the fix was to set the CUDA visible devices to null:

`export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1`

before running the evaluation script in that same terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and the reason was the test.recod file was created while there were no images and annotations in the test folder. I moved the test images and their annotations in the test folder, recreated the test.record and ran the evaluation command again.

My console was showing: "\object_detection-0.1-py3.10.egg\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 1009, in eager_eval_loop
for evaluator in evaluators:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"